# Overriding PostAuthenticate event in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I want to override PostAuthenticate event. In simple asp.net I can do this by override/implementing this method in Global.asax file. I spent a day to find out the solution to implement this in umbraco (umbraco v 4.7.1 (Assembly version: 1.0.4281.20201)) but unable to find any success.

I wrote a class named CustomApplicationGlobal and inherit it from umbraco.Global base class and place it in App_Code folder. I also removed both **App_Browsers.dll** and **App_global.asax.dll** from bin folder. But I observed that my code didn't even execute/run.

Please help me and do let me know how can I do this? Is there is some other alternative to 
do this in umbraco?

Any help in this regard will be highly appriciable.

Regards,

/Rizwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Umbraco 4.8.0 and onwards, the App_global.asax.dll is no longer needed, so you might want to consider upgrading to a newer version.

That said, you don't want to remove App_Browsers.dll, it helps Umbraco target different browser capabilities.

Other than that, I have no experience with the PostAuthenticate event, but Umbraco does not get in the way of your own custom global.asax code. If you remove App_global.asax.dll then also make sure to add a global.asax file that inherits from your own class instead of Umbraco's else it won't get used.
Just putting the class in your App_Code folder may not be enough, make sure to compile it into a dll, that way you can also attach a debugger and see if it gets hit and why it's not executing your code.

You could (for 4.7.1) try and proceed with the route you've taken so far, but leave the dlls and try this approach:
http://blog.mattbrailsford.com/2010/07/11/registering-an-application-start-event-handler-in-umbraco/

Comment: Adding Global.asax file that inherits from your own class instead of Umbraco's else it won't get used.

and 

secondly I removed file from App_Code and use dll instead.